# Open CV Hand Recognition - Making the backProjection of the palm more accurate?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, contour, opencv3.0

I'm using a histogram back projection to detect my palm in a webcam video feed.
I perfectly get the contours for the palm. The problem is, my face and other "skin colour" like objects are also getting detected.
How do I make my histogram detect just my palm and nothing else(Increasing histogram accuracy)?

I use a region of the image of my palm to calculate the histogram before I run the program.
[image]

Notice the door and face getting detected in the background:

[image: Picture of the video feed: notice the door and face getting detected in the background]

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2.putText(frame, "Place region of the {} inside the box".format(objectName), (30,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.85, (255,0,105), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (100, 100), (150, 150), (255, 0 , 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Video Feed", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 108:
        objectColor = frame[100:150, 100:150]
        break
    if key == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()
        break
hsvObjectColor = cv2.cvtColor(objectColor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
objectHist = cv2.calcHist([hsvObjectColor], [0,1], None, [12,15], [0,180,0,256])
cv2.normalize(objectHist, objectHist, 0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

The following code segment detects the palm using the above histogram.

```
hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

objectSegment = cv2.calcBackProject([hsvFrame], [0,1], objectHist, [0,180,0,256], 1)
disc = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
cv2.filter2D(objectSegment, -1, disc, objectSegment)
_, threshObjectSegment = cv2.threshold(objectSegment,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

threshObjectSegment = cv2.merge((threshObjectSegment,threshObjectSegment,threshObjectSegment))
locatedObject = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, threshObjectSegment)

locatedObjectGray = cv2.cvtColor(locatedObject, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, locatedObjectThresh = cv2.threshold(locatedObjectGray, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
locatedObject = cv2.medianBlur(locatedObjectThresh, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using color histogram, it is very difficult to prevent other similar color objects from getting segmented. So once the image segmentation is done and the hand and other stuffs are segmented,u can use connected components and then separate out hand region (by feature matching {hand's features will be different that the noise features}).

Another thing you can explore is temporal superpixel matching. If you can find the exact boundary of the hand in the first frame, you can segment it in consecutive frames using histogram and then locate the hand region by temporally matching the superpixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Haarcascade to detect face and then just put a mask and remove it

Comment: If you give more details on that (exemplifying a good mask, for instance), your answer will be more helpful...

Comment: There is a tutorial by standex on how to use Haar Cascades
:(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88HdqNDQsEk)